# Best C# practice when handling an exception in an API you are providing for other devs

Tags: c#, .net, api

> You can find the entire source here, if you want to share some more
>   pointers:
>
> https://github.com/sergiotapia/DreamInCode.Net

Basically my API is going to give other developers an easy way to access information from http://www.dreamincode.net - and in one of the methods in my library, I wrote this code:

```
public UserProfile FindUserById(int id)
{
    if (id <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("id", id, "The user ID must be greater than 0.");

    string xmlEndPoint = string.Format("http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/xml.php?showuser={0}", id.ToString());
    string xmlResponse;

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            xmlResponse = client.DownloadString(xmlEndPoint);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: " + e.InnerException);
        }
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlResponse))
        throw new Exception("Error: The XML endpoint did not respond.");

    return UserParser.ParseUser(xmlResponse);
}
```

Am I doing this the best way possible with respects to usefulness to other users? Would the .InnerException be enough for other devs to know what went wrong?

Thank you for your time. :)

---

Edit:

So following your advice, I wrote:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        xmlResponse = client.DownloadString(xmlEndPoint);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error: Something went wrong, please check the InnerException.", e);
    }
}
```

Is this the way to go? Is this preserving the stack trace? Am I doing it right?

---

Edit 2:

So this is the ideal solution?

```
//Just let it explode?
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    xmlResponse = client.DownloadString(xmlEndPoint);
}
```

Comment: Still wrong.  1) Don't throw `Exception` 2) Don't wrap at all unless you have useful details to add to the error (which you don't; `something went wrong` is not useful)

Answer (score 5):

- [Don't throw `Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182338.aspx).  Instead, throw an appropriate derived type.
- Don't wrap exceptions (`throw`ing from a `catch`) unless you have additional details to provide.
  (such as what page it failed on, or why you think it failed)
- When wrapping exceptions, always pass the original exception as the `InnerException` constructor parameter.  This provides access to the original stack trace, and any additional information in the exception.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Would I not wrap the `.DownloadString` call in a Catch block and just let the other dev handle it?

Comment: Also don't throw away the original exception.  Stuff it into `InnerException` or log it.  Otherwise you'll have to cross your fingers this repros outside of your production servers/client's machine...

Comment: @SLaks: I'm not following, so it's a good idea to NOT wrap it with a catch block?

Comment: @Sergio: Don't catch an exception if you're not actually doing anything with it.

Comment: @SLaks: Please check my edit and let me know if I'm doing this the better way now.

Answer (score 2):

A few guidelines

- **Don't** throw `Exception` - it's too generic.
- **Don't** rethrow an exception using `throw ex;` - it discards the call stack.
- **Do** throw the ArgumentOutOfRangeException if the wrong parameters are passed
- **Consider** catching and *wrap* exceptions thrown by the code you call. If there is one, use a predefined Exception type that's a good match, otherwise define your own. Never discard a caught exception unless you're *trying* to make it hard to debug.
- **Consider** include additional context about the exception so that the fault can be traced
- **Consider** mentioning the inner exception in your exception message, so that other developers are reminded to look ("An {0} error occurred while downloading {1}; see inner exception for details")

**Update**

To address Scott's comments below on context.

If the request to find a particular user fails, it can be useful to *wrap* the original exception in another that provides more context:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Yes, catch every exception
    var message
        = string.Format(
            "Failed to load user profile for user {0}: {1} ({2})",
                id,
                e.GetType().Name,
                "see inner exception for details");
    throw new InvalidOperationException(message, e);
}
```

This is useful because the actual error may only occur for a particular user id (for example, if the data for this particular user has been corrupted in the underlying database). Providing this kind of additional context provides more information for the developer trying to debug the problem.

Comment: Exception messages aren't really relevant when an exception is handled. The really only become meaningful when an exception is unhandled. Telling an end-user to see the inner exception for details is going to be virtually useless unless 100% of those end users are developers and the application provides an unhandled exception dialog which lets them drill into the details. The API consumers will most certainly be developers and should already know to check the inner exception if needed, particularly if all they get is a general `Exception`.

Comment: Also, you should only catch exceptions thrown by the code you call *if you can do something meaningful about the exception*. Simply catching an exception to wrap it and rethrow it is wasteful and adds complexity to the stack trace that can actually make it harder to debug. However, if you must rethrow an exception you should always use `throw` instead of `throw ex` because `throw ex` will break the stack trace. (As you mentioned.)

Comment: End users should *never* see the contents of an exception message *ever* - not under any circumstances. At the very least they're unfriendly; at worst a security risk. Exception messages are for *developer consumption* (sometimes for IT). When I'm consuming a library and something goes wrong, having *full* information about the failure is necessary for me to do my job. If the library actively conceals information about exceptions (by discarding stack frames, or failing to wrap the original exception), then it's *developer hostile* - and I'll either rewrite it or switch to another library.

Comment: What additional context are you referring to and where would it be stored? Again, the exception itself is really for other developers to know that something went wrong and any tracing of what happened is possible by inspecting the call stack.

Comment: I agree that "simply catching an exception to wrap it and rethrow it is wasteful" - but catching an exception to *add context* and rethrow it can be very useful. It's a similar practice to a method guard clause: instead of a mysterious null reference exception, you get an ArgumentNullException saying "You forgot to supply argument Fu".

Comment: The only way an end user would *never* see the contents of an exception message is for the application code itself to be written so that it catches *every possible exception that could ever be thrown under all possible conditions*. The only other way would be for the application to provide a global exception handler and completely eat all uncaught exceptions which can lead to very unpredictable behavior in the application.

Comment: I never implied the library should discard stack frames, but it should only wrap an exception if bubbling the original exception would be meaningless or confusing to the developer calling that library. An `ArgumentNullException` is completely different than catching a `NullReferenceException` and then adding context (somewhere) that says an argument provided was null.

Comment: Exactly. Adding *context* helps *debugging*. (I only mentioned discarding stack frames for the benefit of others reading this, apologies if you though it directed at you.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3563/discussion-between-scott-dorman-and-bevan)

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- If the existing .NET exceptions fit your needs, use them. The `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` seems appropriate in your example.
- Otherwise, simply create a new exception class and include whatever additional data is needed to accurately describe the error.
- Consider whether upper layers of code need to "filter" exceptions in some way (i.e. catch some and let others continue unwinding). If yes, you may want to consider designing your own  exception inheritance hierarchy, so exceptions may be easily filtered by type.
- In any case, try to be more specific than just plain `Exception`.
- Consider whether exception messages can "bubble-up" all the way to the end user. This may or may not be a good idea depending on circumstances.
- If you (or rather, clients of your API) let user see exception messages, consider localizing them.
- Document your exceptions. You can use `<exception>` tag in `///`-style comments to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458909/best-c-practice-when-handling-an-exception-in-an-api-you-are-providing-for-other/7458920#7458920) covers most of your issues/concerns. As mentioned, you should rarely (if ever) throw a general Exception and you should rarely (if ever) simply wrap an existing exception and throw a new one. The problem with the code you have here

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        xmlResponse = client.DownloadString(xmlEndPoint); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        throw new Exception("Error: " + e.InnerException); 
    } 
}
```

is that the consumers of your API will be required to catch `Exception` and then inspect the `InnerException` for the actual details of what went wrong. Instead, if you just wrote the code like

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
{ 
     xmlResponse = client.DownloadString(xmlEndPoint); 
}
```

any API consumer would see the actual (probably more meaningful) exception that was thrown by the `WebClient` call.

All of that being said, if the idea behind your API is to hide the fact that when a user calls `FindUserById` they are actually going out and hitting a web service somewhere and any exceptions thrown by the `WebClient` call would actually be more "noise" (or otherwise be more confusing to your API consumers) then it is acceptable to catch the exception and throw a more meaningful one (making sure to provide the original exception in the `InnerException`). However, since you are effectively throwing two exceptions (`ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and `Exception`) your API consumers aren't really getting a more meaningful exception.

The `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is appropriate (although if you are using .NET 4 you should really be using the Code Contracts stuff in which case your argument check really should just be a `Contract.Requires<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(id > 0, "The user ID must be greater than 0.");`. The general `Exception` throws should either be removed or replaced with a more meaningful exception type.